# Generation of a counter variable for episodes in panel data in stata

Tags: panel, stata, longitudinal

I am trying to generate a counter variable that describes the duration of a temporal episode in panel data.
I am using long format data that looks something like this:

```
clear
input byte id int time byte var1 int aim1
1 1 0 .
1 2 0 .
1 3 1 1
1 4 1 2
1 5 0 .
1 6 0 .
1 7 0 .
2 1 0 .
2 2 1 1
2 3 1 2
2 4 1 3
2 5 0 . 
2 6 1 1
2 7 1 2
end
```

I want to generate a variable like `aim1` that starts with a value of 1 when `var1==1`, and counts up one unit with each subsequent observation per ID where `var1` is still equal to 1. For each observation where `var1!=1`, `aim1` should contain missing values.

I already tried using `rangestat (count)` to solve the problem, however the created variable does not restart the count with each episode:

```
ssc install rangestat
gen var2=1 if var1==1
rangestat (count) aim2=var2, interval(time -7 0) by (id)
```

Comment: `rangestat (count)` is indeed intended to do something quite different.

Comment: This is a fine question, but in essence a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two ways to do it: (1) from first principles, but see [this paper for more](http://https:/https://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=dm0029) and (2) using `tsspell` from SSC.

```
clear
input byte id int time byte var1 int aim1
1 1 0 .
1 2 0 .
1 3 1 1
1 4 1 2
1 5 0 .
1 6 0 .
1 7 0 .
2 1 0 .
2 2 1 1
2 3 1 2
2 4 1 3
2 5 0 . 
2 6 1 1
2 7 1 2
end

bysort id (time) : gen wanted = 1 if var1 == 1 & var1[_n-1] != 1 
by id: replace wanted = wanted[_n-1] + 1 if var1 == 1 & missing(wanted)

tsset id time
ssc inst tsspell 

tsspell, cond(var1 == 1)

list, sepby(id _spell)

     +---------------------------------------------------------+
     | id   time   var1   aim1   wanted   _seq   _spell   _end |
     |---------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |  1      1      0      .        .      0        0      0 |
  2. |  1      2      0      .        .      0        0      0 |
     |---------------------------------------------------------|
  3. |  1      3      1      1        1      1        1      0 |
  4. |  1      4      1      2        2      2        1      1 |
     |---------------------------------------------------------|
  5. |  1      5      0      .        .      0        0      0 |
  6. |  1      6      0      .        .      0        0      0 |
  7. |  1      7      0      .        .      0        0      0 |
     |---------------------------------------------------------|
  8. |  2      1      0      .        .      0        0      0 |
     |---------------------------------------------------------|
  9. |  2      2      1      1        1      1        1      0 |
 10. |  2      3      1      2        2      2        1      0 |
 11. |  2      4      1      3        3      3        1      1 |
     |---------------------------------------------------------|
 12. |  2      5      0      .        .      0        0      0 |
     |---------------------------------------------------------|
 13. |  2      6      1      1        1      1        2      0 |
 14. |  2      7      1      2        2      2        2      1 |
     +---------------------------------------------------------+
```

The approach of `tsspell` is very close to what you ask for, except (a) its counter (by default `_seq` is 0 when out of spell, but `replace _seq = . if _seq == 0` gets what you ask (b) its auxiliary variables (by default `_spell` and `_end`) are useful in many problems. You must install `tsspell` before you can use it with `ssc install tsspell`.